# Слайдер с текстовой навигацией

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, плагин, slider

Есть задача - сделать обычный слайдер, но вместо обычной навигации (в виде точек или цифр) должен быть текст или можно сделать несколько `div` в которых можно будет прописать текст. Сайт стоит на `cms wordpress`, если данный функционал можно решить при помощи какого либо плагина, будет отлично. Прикреплю фото, что бы задача была более понятна:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычные же табы  https://jqueryui.com/tabs/  вариант 2 http://dimox.name/universal-jquery-tabs-script/

Comment: @Jean-Claude Да, у меня удалось подключить это. Но при клики просто меняется контент, а мне нужен эффект пролистывания, как на слайдерах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов сотни. К примеру на библиотеке [Tiny Carousel](http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/), выглядеть будет так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider1').tinycarousel();
  var slider = $("#slider1").data("plugin_tinycarousel");

  $('#gotoslide1').click(function(e) {
    slider.move(0);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#gotoslide2').click(function(e) {
    slider.move(1);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#gotoslide3').click(function(e) {
    slider.move(2);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/simple/tinycarousel.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style>
  #slider1 .viewport {
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
  }
  #slider1 .overview li {
    height: 350px;
    width: 500px;
    border: medium none;
  }
  #slider1 .overview li > img {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/simple/jquery.tinycarousel.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="gotoslide1">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="#" id="gotoslide2">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="#" id="gotoslide3">Ссылка 3</a>

<div id="slider1">
  <div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
      <li>
        <img src="http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/simple/images/picture6.jpg" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat adipisci, debitis doloribus qui sapiente. Delectus ullam debitis, nostrum commodi quam, quas incidunt ea inventore, sapiente tempora aspernatur earum neque? Minus! Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente laudantium saepe, porro quam temporibus quaerat eaque tempora soluta accusamus et? Voluptas ullam exercitationem, harum sapiente quo tempore velit atque porro?
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/simple/images/picture5.jpg" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam neque, consectetur dicta voluptatum modi alias assumenda reiciendis at iure error accusantium, veritatis placeat laudantium quos, porro. Illum consectetur tempora totam. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi animi magni accusantium architecto possimus vitae sequi, blanditiis eveniet in. Voluptatum numquam fuga asperiores nam nesciunt nisi, doloribus quasi quos aspernatur.</li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/examples/simple/images/picture4.jpg" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur est dolorem reprehenderit deserunt quae nulla officia eos voluptate molestiae. Fugit temporibus dolore quidem sint perspiciatis architecto magnam quae ipsum delectus. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, temporibus, ex! Nesciunt ut harum facilis ex quo asperiores unde deserunt doloribus esse aliquid ea, qui cumque numquam? Praesentium, esse et.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!